# Password creation, encrypting, and saving

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, base64, password-encryption

I know this is probably very simple but I'm a newbie and in first year studying Cyber Security

I've trawled the site and other sites and either most script is in python 2 or just doesn't work for me

I am using repl to test my code to make sure it works

*This is the question we have to complete for our logbook*:

> Write a program which asks the user if they want to encode or decode
>   If encode, ask for an input to encode and a reference
>   Save the encoded value in a file named with the reference
>   If decode, ask if the user wants to decode from previous file or from a string
>   If file, ask the user for reference then read the relevant file and print decoded value
>   If string, ask user for base 64 string and print decoded value

---

This is my current script, I have managed to get user to enter password which then gets encrypted and decrypted as requested, everything works fine, but **am not sure how to add a "reference" for the user as they create a password or save it into a file and ask the user if they want to decode from file or string**:

```
# Note:encoding from base64 and decoding*

from base64 import b64encode
from base64 import b64decode

# Note:user input a password*

Password1 = input("Enter password")
encoded = b64encode(Password1.encode())

# Note:prints an encoded password*

print (encoded.decode('ascii'))

# Note:decode user input password*

decoded = b64decode(encoded)
print (decoded)

# Note:figure how to save password into a file*

save_path = ('passwords')
name_of_file = input ("What is the name of the file: ")
```

Comment: Just to note: you aren't encrypting anything. Encryption is a form of encoding that requires additional knowledge in order to decode the encrypted text. The only thing you need to decode something that has been base64-encoded is the encoded text itself, so it's not encryption.

Comment: Cheers for reply, so I get this back when I run it, the encoded text IEhlbGxv is not encrypted? : Enter password Hello
IEhlbGxv
b' Hello'
What is the name of the file:

Comment: It's not encrypted (though it may *look* that way, because you can't to base64-decoding in your head), because you don't need any other information to decode it. Base64-encoding alone, at best, *obfuscates* some text.

Comment: The purpose of base64-encoding is to take arbitrary binary data and represent it using only printable 7-bit ASCII characters (namely, the upper- and lowercase letters, the numerals 0-9, and couple of punctuation symbols, for a total of 64 different characters--hence the name).

Comment: name_of_file is the reference to the file. What you want to figure out, is how to read and write from files.

Comment: It's unclear from the quoted question what it means by "a reference" — so it's difficult to answer _your_ question.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, sorry if you found it a bit unclear Martin it's all I've got to work with myself, will email lecturer to get a bit of clarity :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a couple different questions here.

First, how to save the output a file.

```
reference = prompt("Enter reference")
with open(reference + ".txt", "w+") as f:
    f.write( ... ) # put your output here like you were using print 
    f.close()
```

Second, how to ask the user if they want to decode from a file or from a string.

```
mode = input("file or string")
if mode is "file":
   #open and read from file
elif mode is "string":
   #prompt for password
else:
    print("error: unknown mode")
```